# Creating references in syllabus with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I am currently preparing a syllabus for a course and would like to use Biblatex to do so. I am using the Biblatex-Chicago package with author-date style.

I have a subsection for each topic of the class and would like list two or three references. I played around with `\fullcite` but it does not produce the desired result as the references are not hanging. Any tips how to best do this. I assume there is a way to use `\printbibliography` to do this but I could not figure out how. Below is the screenshot to illustrate my point. The first entry is created with \fullcite, the second one with \prinbibliography.

I would like to have an option to create hanging entries with \fullcite or something similar and without the "Reference" heading.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Welcome, could you please edit your question to include images of how it currently looks, how you want it to look and some code we can compile to troubleshoot please? Someone might be able to help just with this information but it is quicker for you and easier for everyone if you provide this information.

Comment: Thank you @LaccaseTVersicolor I just posted a screenshot to illustrate what I want to achieve.

Comment: If the only thing that stops you from using `\printbibliography` is the heading, use `\printbibliography[heading=none]`.

Comment: Thank you @moewe! That's very helpful but I would need to use it per subsection and only print the refs from this subsection.

Comment: You can add the refsection=subsection option in the preamble, or use the \newrefsection command. Check the manual for "refsection".

Comment: @JamesClawson Do you want to write up a quick answer with that suggestion?

Comment: @moewe I am using this option now and it is almost self-explanatory. You just add refsection=subsection as an option to the preamble and every time you use /printbibliography it will only print the citations within the respective subsection.

Answer (score 3):

As @moewe suggested, use `\printbibliography[heading=none]` to suppress printing **References** before the full citation. In order to print only the references from a single subsection, add `refsection=subsection` into the call to the Biblatex package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,refsection=subsection]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{sources.bib}
@book{Kuhn1957,
  author = {Kuhn, Thomas S.},
  date = {1957},
  title = {The Copernican Revolution},
  subtitle = {Planetary Astronomy in the Development of
Western Thought},
  location = {Cambridge, MA},
  publisher = {Harvard University Press}
}

@book{Kuhn1977,
  author = {Kuhn, Thomas S.},
  date = {1977},
  title = {The Essential Tension},
  subtitle = {Selected Studies in Scientific Tradition and Change},
  location = {Chicago and London},
  publisher = {University of Chicago Press}
}

@book{Laudan1977,
  author = {Laudan, Larry},
  date = {1977},
  title = {Progress and Its Problems},
  subtitle = {Towards a Theory of Scientific Growth},
  location = {Berkeley},
  publisher = {University of California Press}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{sources.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Sources}

\subsection{One subsection}
\nocite{Kuhn1957,Kuhn1977}

\printbibliography[heading=none]

\subsection{A second subsection}
\nocite{Laudan1977}

\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

When typeset, the above document yields the following:
[image: syllabus with authoryear]

The option also works with biblatex-chicago's author-date style, as you seem to be using in your example. Just change the second line:

```
\usepackage[authordate,refsection=subsection]{biblatex-chicago}
```

Result:
[image: syllabus with biblatex-chicago authordate style]